# How can I tell Drush in which folder should a module be copied?

Tags: drush

Is there a way to make Drush download modules into a specified folder besides sites/all/modules (e.g. sites/all/contrib, sites/all/core)?

If this makes a difference, I am using Drush 4.4.

Comment: I think instead of `sites/all/contrib`, you wanted to write `sites/all/modules/contrib`, right? ;) Btw., `sites/all/modules/core` doesn't really make sense, because core modules (which MUSTN'T get hacked) simply get into `modules` directory, and they do not get downloaded later - they just get updated on a regular Drupal update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've not tried it but apparently.

```
drush help dl
```

> --destination Path to which the
>   project will be copied. If you're
>   providing a relative path, note it is
>   relative to the drupal root (if
>   bootstrapped).

Comment: For `sites/all/contrib` you just need to crate this dir, drush will recognize it and use for all contrib modules

Answer (score 23):

You can default this to, for example, sites/all/modules/contrib, in your .drush/drushrc.php file.

```
$command_specific['dl'] = array('destination' => 'sites/all/modules/contrib');
```

Also note that you won't be able to exclude the 'modules' part of the path, as Drupal uses this to scan for modules.

There are [6 places this file can live](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/examples%21example.drushrc.php/master):

> 1. Drupal site folder (e.g. sites/{default|example.com}/drushrc.php).
> 2. Drupal /drush and sites/all/drush folders, or the /drush folder in the directory above the Drupal root.
> 3. In any location, as specified by the --config (-c) option.
> 4. User's .drush folder (i.e. ~/.drush/drushrc.php).
> 5. System wide configuration folder (e.g. /etc/drush/drushrc.php).
> 6. Drush installation folder.

Comment: Thanks for posting it as a separate answer. This is the real answer for defining the default download directory [as I said earlier](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1233/drush-default-folder/1235?noredirect=1#comment101798_1235). :) +1 for that. (Btw. I hope the OP will change the accepted answer to this one. ;) )

Comment: For `sites/all/contrib` you just need to crate this dir, drush will recognize it and use for all contrib modules. For different dir use above answer with `drushrc.php` settings.